# passing arguments between c and inline assembly

Tags: c++, c, x86, inline-assembly

I have a question about passing arguments between c and inline assembly

I'm having trouble passing an array into my inline assembly. I keep getting the error 'error: memory input 1 is not directly addressable'

Here is an example of my code:

```
void main()
{
    char name[] = "thisisatest";
        __asm__ ("\
        .intel_syntax noprefix     \n\
        mov eax, %[name]           \n\
        inc (eax)                  \n\
       "
    :/*no output*/
    :[name]"m"(name)
    );
}
```

This should increment the first letter of my string (making it 'u'), but it doesn't build.

Ideas?

Comment: That code won't even compile.  Can you show a real example?

Comment: I know it wont compile, thats what i'm asking for help on

Comment: different compilers have different support and syntax for inline assembly - it would help if you state the compiler you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Incase anyone else comes across this I got it working.

```
void main()
{
    char name[] = "thisisatest";
        __asm__ ("\
        .intel_syntax noprefix     \n\
        lea, eax, %[name]          \n\
        inc BYTE PTR [eax]          \n\
       "
    :/*no output*/
    :[name]"m"(name[0])
    );
}
```

The key was passing in the first element of the array as a memory parameter, then asking for the effective address. I then had a pointer to my string. Hope this helps others

Answer (score 2):

You can't pass arrays into inline assembly (except contained in structs) as they convert to pointers, and you can't apply a memory constraint to that pointer as it isn't an lvalue.

You can pass an element of an array in:

```
asm ("incb %0" : "+g" name[0] : : ); // AT&T syntax
```

Or it address:

```
asm volatile ("incb (%0)" : : "r" name : "memory"); // AT&T syntax
```

Also if you switch assembler syntax in inline assembler you must restore it afterwards and not use memory asm operands as these will be in the wrong syntax.

Edit: omitted the variable name in the second code fragment, and added a bracket in the first.

Comment: you can use `asm("incb %0" : : "m"(name[0]) : "memory");` - it'll create the same code as saying `asm("incb (%0) : : "r"(name) : "memory");` (or `"r"(&name[0])`).

Comment: From my reading of the manual, in the case of `asm("incb %0" : : "m"(name[0]) : "memory");` the compiler is allowed to assume name[0] doesn't change if a pointer to it has not escaped. However I can't demonstrate it.

Comment: Thanks again Ken (and for the link). I think the link explains whatt was going on. This looks like the ultimate answer: `asm ("movdqu %1, %0" : "=x"(r) : "m"(t[0]));`. You know, I did not get 1 warning with `-Wall` or `-Wextra` in compilers that accepted the original statement.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do &name try just name, an array always points to the space in memory where it is located. 
Right now what you're trying to do is putting the array 'thisisatest' into a register (eax) that can't hold so much data.

The register can either hold a few chars (depending on register size) or the address of where the array is located

Comment: I've tried with name and &name, I want it to pass the address of name (i.e. eax holds a pointer to my string)

Comment: Then what I think is going on is that the assembly compiler differentiates pointers and arrays (even thought they both have the same value) in that case you probably have to proceed in the way you thought, by doing char *nameptr = name.