# Error : cannot compile this unexpected cast lvalue yet

Tags: c++, macos, inline-assembly, clang++

I'm testing against Apple Clang and I'm encountering an error I have not experienced in the past. The code is as follow, and it replaces the `_mm_set_epi64x` intrinsic if its missing.

```
#if defined(__clang__)
#  define GCC_INLINE inline
#  define GCC_INLINE_ATTRIB __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__))
#elif (GCC_VERSION >= 30300) || defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
#  define GCC_INLINE __inline
#  define GCC_INLINE_ATTRIB __attribute__((__gnu_inline__, __always_inline__, __artificial__))
#else
#  define GCC_INLINE inline
#  define GCC_INLINE_ATTRIB
# endif

...

GCC_INLINE __m128i GCC_INLINE_ATTRIB
MM_SET_EPI64X(const word64 a, const word64 b)
{
    const word64 t[2] = {b,a}; __m128i r;
    asm ("movdqu %1, %0" : "=x"(r) : "m"(t));
    return r;
}
```

The error is:

```
c++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -c sha.cpp
In file included from sha.cpp:24:
./cpu.h:689:39: error: cannot compile this unexpected cast lvalue yet
        asm ("movdqu %1, %0" : "=x"(r) : "m"(t));
```

The Apple Clang version is:

```
$ c++ --version
Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

According to [Clang Bug 20201](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-bugs/2014-July/035325.html), the issue is already fixed. My problems with the 20201 bug are:

1. I don't know if its the same issue
2. the problem is not explained
3. a workaround is not offered
4. Apple has abandoned its software

Because of (4), I have to attempt to fix it. Because of (2) and (3), I don't know how to fix it.

What is the problem, and how do I fix it?

Comment: I cannot access the bug database right now, but looking at [this post](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-bugs/2010-July/013929.html), perhaps there is some sort of const problem? What happens if you drop the `const` from `word64 t[2] = {b,a};`?

Comment: Thanks Ken. Dropping `const` did not clear the issue.

Comment: Continuing my wild guessing, `word64 a1 = a, b1 =b; word64 t[2] = {b1,a1};`? Or drop the `const`s from the prototype? Otherwise, I'm all out of wild guesses!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, random guessing time, but it seems to work... Looking around at related bug reports, there is [this posting](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-bugs/2010-July/013929.html) that says:

> This was fixed by the work to remove cv-qualifiers from non-class rvalues.

This suggests to me that there is some `const` attribute left hanging around in internal structures, so something like this:

```
word64 a1 = a, b1 = b;
word64 t[2] = {b1,a1};
```

Might work, as by copying into an explicitly-declared non-`const` variable, the propagation of the `const`ness of `a` and `b` is prevented, hopefully. This has been confirmed as working by the OP, so their final solution is presented here for posterity:

```
GCC_INLINE __m128i GCC_INLINE_ATTRIB
MM_SET_EPI64X(const word64 a, const word64 b)
{
#if defined(__clang__)
    word64 t1 = a, t2 = b; 
    const word64 t[2] = {t2,t1}; __m128i r;
    asm ("movdqu %1, %0" : "=x"(r) : "m"(t));
    return r;
#else
    const word64 t[2] = {b,a}; __m128i r;
    asm ("movdqu %1, %0" : "=x"(r) : "m"(t));
    return r;
#endif
}
```

Comment: Thanks. CentOS 5/GCC 4.1 is failing with *"memory input 1 is not directly addressable"*. It looks like the issue is bigger than Clang. Maybe I need to look for uses of `_mm_set_epi64x` and attempt to convert them to `_mm_set_epi64`. I think the only difference is the arguments `a` and `b` are reversed. Or maybe `memcpy` it (I seem to recall SunCC generates bad code with a `memcpy`...).

Comment: Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455923/passing-arguments-between-c-and-inline-assembly), you cannot use an array, but instead should do `struct { word64 t[2]; }t = {t2, t1};` or something similar, or use the `_mm128` types.